# Proving Riemann integrability for piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, proof-writing, riemann-integration

**Question:** Prove the function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x) = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x=\frac{1}{n}$ for any positive integer $n$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$ is Riemann integrable.

**My attempt:**

To prove this, I need to show that there exists a partition $P$ such that the difference between the upper and lower Darboux sums (denoted $\mathcal U(P,f)$ and $\mathcal L(P,f)$ respectively) is less than any $\epsilon>0$.

I have the following formulae:

- $\mathcal U(P,f)=\sum^n_{i=1} M_i\Delta x_i$
- $\mathcal L(P,f)=\sum^n_{i=1} m_i\Delta x_i$
- $m_i= \inf\{f(x):x_{i-1} \le x \le x_i\}$
- $M_i=\sup\{f(x):x_{i-1} \le x \le x_i\}$
- $\Delta x_i= x_i - x_{i-1}$

However, to begin this computations I need a partition $P$. How should one go about determining this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to see how many of the points $1/n$ lie outside the interval $[0,\epsilon /2]$. Say at most there are $k$ such points $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_k=1$. Now your partition $P$ should include points $0,\epsilon/2, 1$ and points around $x_i$ which are $\epsilon/2k$ apart.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh so are you saying $P = \{0, \frac{\epsilon}{2}, 1\}$?

Comment: Read again. The partition include these three points and more points around $x_i$. Something like $0,\epsilon /2,y_1,x_1,y_2,y_3,x_2,y_4,y_5,x_3,y_6,\dots,y_{2k-3},x_{k-1},y_{2k-2},y_{2k-1},1$. The thing to note is that $y_{2i}-y_{2i-1}<\epsilon/2k$.

Comment: Thus each $x_i$ lies between two $y_j$ and these two $y$'s differ by at most $\epsilon/2k$. I don't want to write a full answer because that takes away the joy from you. Try to understand the reason why this kind of partition would work and write an answer yourself. Do let me know if you need more clarity. The question is not difficult.

Comment: So this could be $P=\{ 0, \frac{\epsilon}{2}, \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2k}, 1\}$ where $\epsilon > 0$ and $k \in \mathbb Z^{>0}$?

Comment: No the partition includes both $x$ and $y$ points mentioned in my comments. The total number of points in partition is $3k+1$. You just can't do with $3,4$ points.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Why is the partition in terms of both $x$ and $y$? I thought it was usually just in terms of $\epsilon, a, b$ (say for $f$ mapping from $[a,b]$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108123/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-viv4660).

Answer (score 2):

pick arbitrary $x>0$ we know that there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\frac{1}{n}< x $ because $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$ . Now we know that there are atmost finite number of discontinuities on $[\frac{1}{n}, 1]$ hence your function is integrable on $[\frac{1}{n},1]$ Since this holds for arbitrary $x$ we can say that function is integrable on interval $[x,1]$ for any $x>0$.Hence it is Riemann Integrable on $[0,1]$ using  following theorem.

> $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, and $f$ is integrable on $[c, b]$ for all  $ c \in$
>   $(a, b)$, then f is integrable on $[a, b]$.

infact you can calculate value integral of function by *proving* following

$$\int_{0}^1 f  = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{\frac{1}{k+1}}^{\frac{1}{k}} f = 0$$

can you prove the threorem and above statement?

Comment: I'm not sure I can prove the theorem. Intuitively, it makes sense though since the "for all $c \in (a,b)$" part pretty much includes $c=a$. Do you know where I can find a proof of this theorem?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want a elementary detailed proof.

Fix $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0}<\epsilon/2$. Then we can split $[0,1]$ into $[0,\frac{1}{n_0}]$ and $[\frac{1}{n_0},1]$. Notice that $[\frac{1}{n_0},1]$ contains only finitely many $\frac{1}{n}$, therefore $f$ has only finitely many discontinuous points on $[\frac{1}{n_0},1]$. Thus $f$ is integrable on $[\frac{1}{n_0},1]$(why?). Then we can choose a partition $P:x_0,x_1,...x_N$ of $[\frac{1}{n_0},1]$ such $U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\epsilon/2$.

We consider $Q=P\cup\{0\}$. Let $Q:y_0,...y_{N+1}$.

Notice that $y_1=x_0,y_2=x_1,...y_{N+1}=x_N$.

Thus

$U(Q,f)-L(Q,f)$

$=(M_1-m_1)\Delta y_1+\sum_{i=2}^{N+1}(M_i-m_i)\Delta y_i$

$=(M_1-m_1)\Delta y_1+\sum_{i=1}^{N}(M_i-m_i)\Delta x_i$

$<(1-0)(\frac{1}{n_0}-0)+U(P,f)-L(P,f)$

$=\frac{1}{n_0}+\epsilon/2$

$<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2$

Comment: I have a few questions: (1) Why does $[\frac{1}{n_0}, 1]$ contain only finitely many $\frac{1}{n}$? (2) For the partition $P$, what is $x_N$? Is this $1$? (3) How did you get the difference of the Darboux sums for $P$ being $< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$?

Comment: (1): if $\frac{1}{n}\in[\frac{1}{n_0},q]$, then $n<=n_0$

Comment: (2): $x_N$ is 1, since $P$ is defined to be a partition of $[0,1]$

Comment: (3) since $f$ contains only finitely many discontinuous points on $[\frac{1}{n_0},1]$, we have $f$ is integrable on $[\frac{1}{n_0},1]$, therefore, by definition, we can choose a partition $P$ such that $U(P,f)-L(P,f)<\epsilon/2$ (does this answer your question? Do you know how to prove "discontinuous on only finitely many points implies integrability"?)